# Brownian motion, stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Question: Let $W$ be a Brownian motion with $W(0) = 0$. Determine $E[\cos{W(t)}+\sin{W(t)}]$.

I let

$Y=\cos{W(t)}$

$dY=-\sin{W(t)}dW(t)-\frac{1}{2}\cos{W(t)}(dW(t))^2=-\sin{W(t)}dW(t)-\frac{1}{2}\cos{W(t)}dt$

and similarly,

$Z=\sin{W(t)}$

$dZ=\cos{W(t)}dW(t)-\frac{1}{2}\sin{W(t)}dt$

But I am not sure how to continue now.

$E[Y(t)]=\cos{W(0)}-\int^{t}_{0}\frac{1}{2}\cos{W(s)}ds$

and

$E[Z(t)]=\sin{W(0)}-\int^{t}_{0}\frac{1}{2}\sin{W(s)}ds$, am I right?

Comment: No, it's not right because you have forgotten to take the expectation on the rght-hand side. From my point of view, it's overkill to solve this problem using Itô's formula; it can be solved using elementary calculations, see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3032298/36150) for $\mathbb{E}\sin(W_t)$.

Comment: Is $E[Y(t)]=e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}$ correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need to compute $E[\cos{W(t)}+\sin{W(t)}]$ is the fact that
$$
W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t).
$$ By definition, it holds
$$
E[\cos{W(t)}+\sin{W(t)}]= \int_\mathbb{R} (\cos x+\sin x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} dx,
$$ where $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}$ is the probability density function of $W(t)$. Since we have characteristic function of normal distributions
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{i\xi x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} dx = \int_\mathbb{R} (\cos \xi x +i\sin \xi x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} dx =e^{-\frac{t\xi^2}{2}}, \quad\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R},
$$ by comparing the real and imaginary part on both sides, it follows that
$$
E[\cos{W(t)}+\sin{W(t)}] = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}+0=e^{-\frac{t}{2}}.
$$